# Kotlin incorrectly infers nullable Enum return type when a function call is passed as an argument to another function

Tags: kotlin, generics, enums, type-inference

I may not have done a good job explaining the problem in the title, but here's an example:

```
fun main() {
    acceptEnum(inferType())
}

fun acceptEnum(value: MyEnum?) {}

fun <R : Enum<R>?> inferType(): R = TODO()

enum class MyEnum {
    VALUE
}
```

`inferType()` function infers its return type and bounds it to be a generic nullable enum. `acceptEnum()` function has a nullable enum parameter. When we write `acceptEnum(inferType())`, everything's fine. But if we add one more parameter to `acceptEnum()` and pass `inferType()` there again, here's what happens:

```
fun main() {
    // first inferType() does not compile with an error:
    // Type mismatch: inferred type is MyEnum? but MyEnum was expected
    acceptEnum(inferType(), inferType())
}

fun acceptEnum(value: MyEnum?, value2: MyEnum?) {}
```

If we add more parameters, every `inferType()` call except the last one produces this error.

Is this a compiler bug or am I doing something wrong?

**Update**

Kotlin forum post: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-incorrectly-infers-nullable-enum-return-type-when-a-function-call-is-passed-as-an-argument-to-another-function/23650

**Update**

Kotlin issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-50232

Comment: Seems like a compiler bug. But out of curiosity, how could you compose a useful function that has a generic return value and no generic parameters? I can’t think of how the function could know what type to return at runtime.

Comment: @Tenfour04, In the actual code Instead of an "inferType()" I have an inline function that converts one enum type to another and it has both a generic parameter and a generic return. But for the sake of simplicity I've provided a simplified example.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a compiler bug. The type argument for `Enum` may not be nullable, but your `R` is nullable.

Since Kotlin 1.7, there is a solution for this. It is [definitely non-nullable types](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/issues/268).
Using this syntax your type definition will become

```kotlin
fun <R : Enum<R & Any>?> inferType(): R = TODO()
```

The `R & Any` guarantees that although `R` is nullable, the type argument for `Enum` is not. Your code will then compile without warnings.